# VBA-JSON: Add entry to Existing File

Tags: json, excel, vba

I'm using excel to modify existing JSON with the VBA-JSON library and I'm effectively trying to do what .push from javascript does, adding another entry to the nested array.

There's this previously posted question which illustrates what I'm trying to do but in the scope of creating a JSON file.

[VBA-JSON Create nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032724/vba-json-create-nested-objects)

The accepted answer while helpful, doesn't show me how to add to what I already have without rebuilding it entirely. I can picture a mess of loops to parse my existing file into strings, then do something similar to what is in the post. I'm curious if there's another way to do it.

```vb
'download json

Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(H.responseText)

Debug.print json(1)("entries")(1)("Date")
'2019-09-25

json(1)("entries")(2)("Date") = "2019-09-26"
'error 9 Subscript out of Range

'upload json
```

```json
[
    {
        "Entries": [
            {
                "Date": 2019-09-25,
                "a": 1,
                "b": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm able to access and modify existing entries but not add to it. I'm guessing this is because the library parses it as a defined array rather than variable? Any ideas on a simple solution or will I have to deconstruct my file into dictionaries/collections and rebuild it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA Json is really just a cheap (and effective) converter/deconverter of a json string into a nested set of dictionaries and collections. So you don't have to *"deconstruct [your] file into dictionaries/collections and rebuild it"* since... it already is. This is why it's necessary to add in the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library to use it.

The struggle you are dealing with is that you are treating every object in your `json` object as a dictionary. Instead you want to `add`(pop) to the `entries` collection. A good way to keep these separate is that in VBA JSON (as far as I've seen) if an object is a key/value pair, then it's a `Dictionary` and if it's just an object without a `key` then it's a `Collection`. I'm certain there is more nuance there, but it works well in this scenario.

Consider:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Json As Object
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson("[{""Entries"":[{""Date"": 2019-09-25,""a"": 1,""b"": 2}]}]")

    Dim entry1 As Object
    Set entry1 = Json(1)("Entries")

    Stop '<--inspect Locals and see that we have a Collection here

    'Add to the collection (different then adding to a dictionary)
    'We will add a dictionary to the collection though
    Json(1)("Entries").Add New Dictionary

    'Now add to the dictionary.
    Json(1)("Entries")(2).Add "Date", "2019-09-26"

    Stop

    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Json)

    'Alternatively you could create the dictionary and add your keys, then `pop` your entries
    Dim Entry As Dictionary
    Set Entry = New Dictionary
    Entry.Add "Date", "2019-09-26"
    Entry.Add "a", "2"
    Entry.Add "b", "3"

    Json(1)("Entries").Add Entry

    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Json)
End Sub
```

This should spit out what you are after (I think):

```
[{"Entries":[{"Date":"2019-09-25","a":1,"b":2},{"Date":"2019-09-26"}]}]
```

I guess another way to think through this is that if we want to add a new array to our `Entries` then we have to add a new `Dictionary` object to the `Entries` collection. Then we can add into the dictionary our key/value pairs like `Date`, `a`, and `b`.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for the explanation and code. I'd upvote this but I can't yet. The edit with the alternative is useful reference too, that's what I was thinking after seeing your initial response.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you saw the edit. I was rereading the answer and I was like... "Duh.. this would make more sense if I created the dictionary first, then added it to the collection".

Comment: @JNevill and OP: Brilliant approach, so obvious that it was hidden in plain view, at least for me. Thanks.

Comment: And to add 0.02$:
 `Json(1)("Entries")(2).Add "Dates", array("2019-09-26","2019-01-23","2020-01-24")`